# Failed to start Mongodb

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, deployd

I'm studying pro angularjs by adam freeman. I've installed deployd v0.8.8 and created sportsstore. When I run 'dpd –p 5500 sportsstore\app.dpd' form command prompt, it shows  'Failed to start MongoDB Make sure 'mongod' are in your $PATH or use dpd --mongod option. Ref: http://docs.deployd.com/docs/basics/cli.html bye'.
I've found all the possible answers as much as I can. But still can't solve it. I'm using Windows 7 32-bit. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run like this: http://pastebin.com/raw/apKQb043 (Moved code snippet to pastebin).

Comment: Well, i can't figure out how to escape backtick. Could you execute `which mongod` from the command line?

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean? I run exactly like your answer. By the way, I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: My OS is Windows 7 32-bit. @Mateusz

Comment: Still 'File not found'. @Mateusz

Answer (score 0):

Hello you must install mongodb after this add the path of th folder installation into the windows path environment restart your cli and type again the command

Comment: I don't know how to do this. Could you please explain me clearly? @user6327113

Comment: first go here https://www.mongodb.com/download-center and install the version of mongodb corresponding to your system
be sure to know where you will install it when the installer ask for it

Comment: after this locate the installation folder it must contains some files and a directory named bin double click in bin directory now copy the full path and let's add it to the environment variable 'path' [how](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

Comment: @VincentPaukgyi please be more clear what's the output what's the errors displayed have you installed mongodb and set it in the environment path. i had the same issue a day ago.

Comment: I've done everything you suggested and the error is still the same. I don't know what is happening. @user6327113

Answer (score 0):

from control panel open up advanced system settings.  click on environment variables. under system variables select path and click edit.  then add the directory for your mongodb installation in my case is "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin". P.S if you use windows 8.1 or an earlier release of windows OS type a ";" first.  leave out out the quotation marks.